# Standard icons set in C with Win32

Tags: c, winapi, icons

I am looking for the normal way (that is, the way Microsoft thought about when creating its API) to load standard icons for commands in a pure C program, like the floppy disc image for saving, etc.

The Internet doesn't seem to contain the answer. I know the toolbars of commctl32 can receive a `TB_LOADIMAGES` message that fills an image list with standard icons, but what if I don't need toolbars in my app? I want icons in another control, let's say on an owner-draw button, or a menu item. Is there a way to fill the image list without creating a useless toolbar? Or even better, getting `HICON` or `HBITMAP` handles to avoid the commctl32 dependency?

The loud silence about it in Microsoft's docs, and on the web, makes me think there is no such feature. Maybe when an application is developed with Microsoft tools, the application creator injects as resources in the executable files the default icons the developer chooses in a predefined list? I cannot check it because I only use Unix-like compilers, can somebody confirm that and/or tell me more about default icon usage under Windows?

Also, would it be reliable to assume we can load libraries like `shell32.dll` to use its embedded icons (like all the good old functions that are available since an eternity in `kernel32.dll`, `user32.dll, ...)? I mean, is there a guarantee that icons in libraries will keep their semantics and indexes in future versions of Windows?

Comment: These aren't system provided.

Comment: The most standard image list is available through SHGetImageList, but I'm not sure that's what you're after. MS also makes a few very large icon libraries available [Microsoft Image Libraries](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825). You then have to pick through the library to create the image set your particular program needs.

Comment: Are you looking for the SHGetStockIconInfo API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shgetstockiconinfo)? It defines an official set of ~100 icons https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ne-shellapi-shstockiconid

Comment: @David Heffernan: Interesting statement, so applications tends to always embed all icons they need in their ".rsrc" section?

Comment: @SoronelHaetir: Thank you very much for the "SHGetImageList" function, I didn't know it. The concept of system image list might be exactly what I was looking for, does this kind of list contain both files and command icons? I also tried your link to Microsoft Image Libraries, this is an impressive collection of icons, its existence is a serious clue about the lack of system provided icon set.

Comment: @Simon Mourier: Yes I'm looking for this kind of function, however despite I'm happy to discover it and I will certainly use it soon in my code, this one provides too few necessary icons for commands. I may have to clarify that, I merge the concepts of file icons and cmd icons into a single one because this is what I think MS technologies do, but I might be wrong. My intention is, above all, to display command icons provided by the OS, so that the chances of having an appearance consistent with the user environment would be the best (flat design under Win10, nice colors under Win7, etc.)

Comment: Yes, applications embed their own icons.

Comment: I don't know what *"command icons"* are supposed to be. Though, starting with Windows 8, icons in ICO format have been replaced with glyphs from the [Segoe UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font) family of fonts.

Comment: Well, by talking about "command icon" I wanted to evoke icons suitable to represent "WM_COMMAND" actions. Thank you for bringing the Segoe UI information, it is indeed a noticeable evolution of the icon approach under Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Coming some days later to post the final solution I opted for, just in case somebody would need to use the same. The most normal way to show command icons is to embed them in the application, so despite being unhappy with the creation of a dummy control, I use a temporary toolbar to load the icons in global image lists. This would unlikely fail, but since icons may sometimes be the only thing that indicates to the user what a widget does, I reinforced the conditions with the ability to run a fallback code when something is wrong.

The function that loads the icons is named `WIN32_initIcons()`, because it is supposed to be implemented alongside with something like a `GTK_initIcons()` or `X11_initIcons()` counterpart for Unix-like platforms.

```
HIMAGELIST WIN32_imglst16 = NULL;
HIMAGELIST WIN32_imglst24 = NULL;

bool WIN32_initIcons(void) {

    bool def16 = false;
    bool def32 = false;

    HWND hWnd;

    WIN32_imglst16 = ImageList_Create(16, 16, ILC_COLOR32 | ILC_MASK, 80, 16);
    WIN32_imglst32 = ImageList_Create(24, 24, ILC_COLOR32 | ILC_MASK, 80, 16);

    if (hWnd = CreateWindowA("ToolbarWindow32", NULL, TBSTYLE_LIST, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, (HMENU)0, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL)) {

        if (WIN32_imglst16) {

            SendMessage(hWnd, TB_SETIMAGELIST, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)WIN32_imglst16);

            if (!SendMessage(hWnd, TB_LOADIMAGES, (WPARAM)IDB_STD_SMALL_COLOR, (LPARAM)HINST_COMMCTRL)) def16 = true;
            if (SendMessage(hWnd, TB_LOADIMAGES, (WPARAM)IDB_VIEW_SMALL_COLOR, (LPARAM)HINST_COMMCTRL) != 15) def16 = false;
            if (SendMessage(hWnd, TB_LOADIMAGES, (WPARAM)IDB_HIST_SMALL_COLOR, (LPARAM)HINST_COMMCTRL) != 27) def16 = false;
            if (ImageList_GetImageCount(WIN32_imglst16) != 32) def16 = false;

        }

        if (WIN32_imglst24) {

            SendMessage(hWnd, TB_SETIMAGELIST, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)WIN32_imglst24);

            if (!SendMessage(hWnd, TB_LOADIMAGES, (WPARAM)IDB_STD_LARGE_COLOR, (LPARAM)HINST_COMMCTRL)) def24 = true;
            if (SendMessage(hWnd, TB_LOADIMAGES, (WPARAM)IDB_VIEW_LARGE_COLOR, (LPARAM)HINST_COMMCTRL) != 15) def24 = false;
            if (SendMessage(hWnd, TB_LOADIMAGES, (WPARAM)IDB_HIST_LARGE_COLOR, (LPARAM)HINST_COMMCTRL) != 27) def24 = false;
            if (ImageList_GetImageCount(WIN32_imglst24) != 32) def24 = false;

        }

        DestroyWindow(hWnd);

    }


    if (WIN32_imglst16 && !def16) {
        // Load your custom 16x16 fallback icons in the list "WIN32_imglst16" here
        // Don't forget to set "def16 = true" on success
    }

    if (WIN32_imglst24 && !def24) {
        // Load your custom 24x24 fallback icons in the list "WIN32_imglst24" here
        // Don't forget to set "def24 = true" on success
    }

    if (!def16) {
        // Trigger your error management here because 16x16 icons cannot be loaded
        // Maybe, call "ImageList_Destroy(WIN32_imglst16)" and set "WIN32_imglst16 = NULL"
    }

    if (!def24) {
        // Trigger your error management here because 24x24 icons cannot be loaded
        // Maybe, call "ImageList_Destroy(WIN32_imglst24)" and set "WIN32_imglst24 = NULL"
    }

    return (def16 && def24);

}
```

Note: In simple C, use `<stdbool.h>` to define the `bool` value.